# Sort results in mongo by greatest improvement between fields

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to write a mongo query that will find the greatest improvement in rank between 2015 and 2016. This is what I wrote, however the results aren't correct and I am not sure how to write this correctly.

```
db.car.find({}).sort({"2015rank - 2016rank / 2015rank" : -1}).pretty();
```

This is a sample of the results

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5a22c8e562c2e489c5df70fa"),
    "2016rank" : 1,
    "Dealershipgroupname" : "AutoNation Inc.?",
    "Address" : "200 S.W. 1st Ave.",
    "City/State/Zip" : "Fort Lauderdale, FL 33301",
    "Phone" : "(954) 769-7000",
    "Companywebsite" : "www.autonation.com",
    "Topexecutive" : "Mike Jackson",
    "Topexecutivetitle" : "chairman & CEO",
    "Totalnewretailunits" : "337,622",
    "Totalusedunits" : "225,713",
    "Totalfleetunits" : "3,738",
    "Totalwholesaleunits" : "82,342",
    "Total_units" : "649,415",
    "Total_number_of _dealerships" : 260,
    "Grouprevenuealldepartments*" : "$21,609,000,000",
    "2015rank" : 1
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a22c8e562c2e489c5df70fb"),
    "2016rank" : 5,
    "Dealershipgroupname" : "Sonic Automotive Inc.?",
    "Address" : "4401 Colwick Road",
    "City/State/Zip" : "Charlotte, NC 28211",
    "Phone" : "(704) 566-2400",
    "Companywebsite" : "www.sonicautomotive.com",
    "Topexecutive" : "B. Scott Smith",
    "Topexecutivetitle" : "CEO",
    "Totalnewretailunits" : "134,288",
    "Totalusedunits" : "119,174",
    "Totalfleetunits" : "1,715",
    "Totalwholesaleunits" : "35,098",
    "Total_units" : "290,275",
    "Total_number_of _dealerships" : 112,
    "Grouprevenuealldepartments*" : "$9,731,778,000",
    "2015rank" : 4
```

Comment: You can add another field to your documents which evaluates to `2015rank - 2016rank / 2015rank` and then sort on that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) for that.

**UPDATED:** I added the `$match` stage which skips the documents if the data type of the `2016rank` or `2015rank` field is not a double or integer.

Code example:

```
db.car.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                {"2016rank": {$type: 1}},
                {"2016rank": {$type: 16}}
            ],
            $or: [
                {"2015rank": {$type: 1}},
                {"2015rank": {$type: 16}}
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "rankIncrease": {
                $divide:[
                    {
                        $subtract: ["$2016rank", "$2015rank"]
                    },
                    "$2015rank"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {"rankIncrease" : -1}
    }
])
```

Comment: I receive an error "cant $subtract a string from a int"

Comment: I think that some `2015rank` and/or `2016rank` fields contains are string data type (not integer).

Comment: Just looked at the json file looks like some of the 2015 rank fields contain question marks. What would be the best way to skip these?